# fread in a while cicle with restriction - c programming

Tags: c, struct, while-loop, fread

i have this while cicle and i need print only the registries where the apagado variable='\0'.

my structure is:

```
typedef struct {

char apagado; 
char prop[MAXPLEN];
char mat[6];
double valor;
} veiculo_t;
```

...
sample of code:

```
{
    FILE *f=fopen("veic.dat", "rb");
    veiculo_t *t = malloc(sizeof(veiculo_t));
    while(fread(t, sizeof(char), sizeof(*t), f))
    print_registry(t); //
   }
```

with this code prints all the registries, independently the value of apagado.

Comment: Did you try to use `if (...)` ?

Comment: The sample of code you have shown is insufficient. Where are you testing against the value of `apagado`?

Comment: @Martin i did. i tried **if((*t).apagado='\0')** . Still prints all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong use of parameters:

```
while(fread(t, sizeof(char), sizeof(*t), f))
```

Should be

```
while(fread(t, sizeof(*t), 1, f))
```

The first returns values`0 ... sizeof(*t)`.. The second returns `0 ... 1`.  So to prevent a partially filled structure, use the 2nd form.

```
while(fread(t, sizeof(*t), 1, f)) {
  if (t->apagado == '\0') {
    print_registry(t); //
  }
}
```

Of course, make certain `f` and `t` are not `NULL`.

Comment: @OP In `if((*t).apagado='\0'`, you want to compare using `==`, not assign with `=`.